# tensorflow-hub can`t load BERT model

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

```
bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1",trainable=False)
vocab_file = bert_layer.resolved_object.vocab_file.asset_path.numpy()
do_lower_case = bert_layer.resolved_object.do_lower_case.numpy()
tokenizer = FullTokenizer(vocab_file, do_lower_case)
```

then, it`s not work and report error:Timeout:

```
INFO:absl:Downloading TF-Hub Module 'https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/1'.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/app/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error

TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

/usr/local/app/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1320                 raise URLError(err)
   1321             r = h.getresponse()
   1322         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

i can`t find out why this occurs,anyone can help me ?

Comment: The problem is related to your network connection. Check if the internet was working properly, if the related ports are open, or if the firewall had blocked the access to the URL.

Comment: Could you try downloading updated BERT model from  :- https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/4 ?
If you face exact error, it means you do not have network access to the server where these models are hosted due to firewall .
Else the server where these models are hosted might be down temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to access by using the mirror image backup in China, Specifically, suppose you are having trouble in accessing

```
model = hub.load('https://tfhub.dev/google/yamnet/1')
```

You switch to the mirror image in China, with following:

```
model = hub.load('https://hub.tensorflow.google.cn/google/yamnet/1')
```